# Multiple Choice Django Checkbox Form Validation

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a form with a `favourite_trees` field, which I would like to have its 3 choices show up as check boxes. I'd then like for the user to be able to check 0 to 3 of the check boxes, and to have those results be saved. However, when I try to save my form, the `favourite_trees` field is just saving as an empty list. The other fields are saving correctly. How can I fix it so that the checkboxes checked do save?

forms.py

```
class TreesForm(forms.models.ModelForm):
    favourite_trees = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=TreePreference.TREE_CHOICES,
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
    class Meta:
        model = TreePreference
        fields = (
                'tree_knowledge',
                'tree_type',)
        widgets = {
            'tree_type': forms.HiddenInput(),
        }
```

models.py

```
class TreePreference(models.Model):
    TREE_CHOICES = ('red_trees',
                    'blue_trees',
                    'purple_trees',
                   )
    tree_knowledge = model.CharField(blank=True, max_length=10)
    tree_type = model.CharField(blank=True, max_length=20)
    favourite_trees = models.CharField(choices=TREE_CHOICES, max_length=50, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also a package `django-multiselectfield` that might help you with storing multiple (string) values that do not require a separate model.

Answer (score 1):

Because your `favourite_trees` field is a `CharField` with `choices`, so it only stores one type of tree in `TREE_CHOICES` as a string, you cannot directly use `MultipleChoiceField` to save it. You should use create a separate model called something like `TreeChoice`, then change field `favourite_trees` to a `ManyToManyField` pointing to that model.